# How to prove this identity assuming Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Given $$F \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$$
$$Y|F \sim \mathcal{N}(F, \tau^{-1} I )$$

Show that 
$$
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma + \tau^{-1}I)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $Y-F$ and $F$ are jointly gaussian, then $Y = (Y-F) + F$ is also gaussian.

You can compute the moments from the moments of $Y-F$ and $F$, or using the tower property:

- For the mean:
  $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|F]] = \mathbb{E}[F] = 0$$
- For the variance:
  $$\begin{aligned}
  \mathbb{E}[Y^2] & = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|F]] \\
  & = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{V}[Y|F] + \mathbb{E}[Y|F]^2] \\
  & = \mathbb{E}[\tau^{-1}I + \Sigma] \\
  & = \tau^{-1}I + \Sigma
  \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Please keep in mind that with homework-style questions (e.g. see the [help/on-topic], we aim to give guidance (such as answer questions about specific problems that the student identifies in their own attempt) rather than complete solutions. Leaving issues of potential academic misconduct aside, doing students work for them does not help them nearly as much as helping them to see how to approach the problem and allowing them to complete it themselves.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. Should I delete the answer then?

Comment: @byouness How did you establish $Y-F$ and $F$ are independent gaussians?

Comment: @byouness I don't think that's necessary, but please keep it in mind for next time

Comment: You could change your answer to what the thought process led you to the answer ie. sum of variance and how the mean of affected by the operation. I don't see anything in the given part of the question that states independence, but it is required to get the answer so maybe the incomplete problem was presented?

Comment: Independence is neither stated in the Q nor required to answer it. The marginal distribution of F and the conditional distribution of Y (conditioned on F) are sufficient to establish the result

Comment: @Glen_b this is not a homework. This is simply a detail in a paper that is skipped. I know how to figure out using brutal force but just curious how to do it another way.

Comment: I have reopened

Comment: @Shaowu You should show us your solution using brute force. That way responders will know they need to do something else. And it will establish the credibility of your claim. Keep in mind a scientist's brute force solution might be an engineer's elegant solution, so we really don't know what you mean by that.